# login.php not starting session or setting array

Tags: php, arrays, session, cookies, login-script

I have a `login.php` file that after a valid login it does not seem to be starting a session or storing any information in the session array? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

```
    <?php 
include_once 'accounts/db.php';
include_once 'accounts/dbfunctions.php';

$err = array();

foreach($_GET as $key => $value) {
    $get[$key] = filter($value); //get variables are filtered.
}

if ($_POST['doLogin']=='Login')
{

foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
    $data[$key] = filter($value); // post variables are filtered
}


$user_email = $data['usr_email'];
$pass = $data['pwd'];


if (strpos($user_email,'@') === false) {
    $user_cond = "user_name='$user_email'";
} else {
      $user_cond = "user_email='$user_email'";

}


$result = mysql_query("SELECT `id`,`pwd`,`full_name`,`approved`,`user_level` FROM users WHERE 
           $user_cond
            AND `banned` = '0'
            ") or die (mysql_error()); 
$num = mysql_num_rows($result);

  // Match row found with more than 1 results  - the user is authenticated. 
    if ( $num > 0 ) { 

    list($id,$pwd,$full_name,$approved,$user_level) = mysql_fetch_row($result);

    if(!$approved) {
    //$msg = urlencode("Account not activated. Please check your email for activation code");
    $err[] = "Account not activated. Please check your email for activation code";

    //header("Location: login.php?msg=$msg");
     //exit();
     }

        //check against salt
    if ($pwd === PwdHash($pass,substr($pwd,0,9))) { 
    if(empty($err)){            

     // this sets session and logs user in  
       session_start();
       session_regenerate_id(true); //prevent against session fixation attacks.

       // this sets variables in the session 
        $_SESSION['user_id']= $id;  
        $_SESSION['user_name'] = $full_name;
        $_SESSION['user_level'] = $user_level;
        $_SESSION['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] = md5($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);

        //update the timestamp and key for cookie
        $stamp = time();
        $ckey = GenKey();
        mysql_query("update users set `ctime`='$stamp', `ckey` = '$ckey' where id='$id'") or die(mysql_error());

        //set a cookie 

       if(isset($_POST['remember'])){
                  setcookie("user_id", $_SESSION['user_id'], time()+60*60*24*COOKIE_TIME_OUT, "/");
                  setcookie("user_key", sha1($ckey), time()+60*60*24*COOKIE_TIME_OUT, "/");
                  setcookie("user_name",$_SESSION['user_name'], time()+60*60*24*COOKIE_TIME_OUT, "/");
                   }
          header( 'Location: http://www.example.com' ) ;
         }
        }
        else
        {
        //$msg = urlencode("Invalid Login. Please try again with correct user email and password. ");
        //$err[] = "Invalid Login. Please try again with correct user email and password.";
        header("Location: index.html?p=problem1");
        }
    } else {
        header("Location: index.html?p=problem2");
        //$err[] = "Error - Invalid login. No such user exists";
      }     
}



?>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#logForm").validate();
  });
  </script>
<?php
      /******************** ERROR MESSAGES*************************************************
      This code is to show error messages 
      **************************************************************************/
      if(!empty($err))  {
       echo "<div class=\"msg\">";
      foreach ($err as $e) {
        echo "$e <br>";
        }
      echo "</div>";    
       }
      /******************************* END ********************************/      
      ?>
<div>
<?php
echo "session user id " . $_SESSION['user_id'];
echo "session id" . $sess_user_id;
echo "cookie id" . $cook_user_id;
echo "Session A " . $test1;
Print_r ($_SESSION);
$sid = session_id();
if($sid) {
    echo "Session exists!" . session_id();
} else {
    echo "NOTHING!";
}
echo $_SESSION['user_name'];
echo $_COOKIE['user_id'];
echo $_COOKIE['user_key'];
?>
<a id="11" href="#colorbox" class="Link">Login</a>
</div>
<div style='display:none'>
<div id="colorbox">
  <div id="LoginBox">
    <form action="login.php" method="post" name="logForm" id="logForm">
      <div class="Fields">
      <div id="userName">UserName:</div>
        <input name="usr_email" type="text" class="required" size="25">
      </div>
      <div class="Fields" style="padding-top:5px;">
      <div id="passWord">Password:</div>
        <input name="pwd" type="password" class="required password" size="25">
      </div>
      <div class="Fields" style="padding-top:5px;">
        <input name="remember" type="checkbox" id="remember" value="1">
        Remember me</div>
      <div class="Fields" style="padding-top:5px;text-align:center;">
        <input name="doLogin" type="submit" id="doLogin3" class="button" value="Login">
      </div>
    </form>
    <div id="forgotPasswordLink">
    <a class="sitelink" id="colorboxForgot" href="forgot.php">Forgot Password</a></div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Right now after login I see url index.html?p=problem instead of http://www.example.com

the following echos are empty so I believe that means no information is going into the session array

```
<?php
echo "session user id " . $_SESSION['user_id'];
echo "session id" . $sess_user_id;
echo "cookie id" . $cook_user_id;
echo "Session A " . $test1;
Print_r ($_SESSION);
$sid = session_id();
if($sid) {
    echo "Session exists!" . session_id();
} else {
    echo "NOTHING!";
}
echo $_SESSION['user_name'];
echo $_COOKIE['user_id'];
echo $_COOKIE['user_key'];
?>
```

Comment: is the lower one calling session_start() anywhere? that needs to be on every page you intend to use sessions on

Comment: I think you did not posted entire code because your `if(empty($err)){` may contain parent `if` and problem may be in there.

Comment: I have re-posted with full code. file is a inc.php file

Comment: @KaiQing session_start(); is being called if the user is valid. After if(empty($err)){

Comment: when i echo $err; i just get the word "array" so $err should be empty

Comment: its looking like its failing at  if ($pwd === PwdHash($pass,substr($pwd,0,9))) {

Comment: iv corrected the salt problem, the code is now passing the pass salt test but still no information is being set in the session array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

keep in mind that you should start session at the very top of thd page,ie before anything start.else you will get empty values for session variables. if you wish to use session variables.Move 
    session_start();

to fist line.

sure this will solve ur problem

Comment: adding session_start(); to the top of the login.php did not solve my problem, my echo is still returning no data

Comment: Im getting Array ( ) Session exists!a2e63caa6bdeea303bc779cddb6ce95a now from the echos after valid login

Comment: I dont want to start a session on login.php untill after i have confirmed a user is valid. That is why it is where it is. This code is OS and works as a stand-alone login I am trying to put it in an incl file so that once a user is logged into a valid session they see content only offered to those with a valid session

Comment: @webmasteralexl did you managed to set session values before? else Try this, Create a new page with session_start(); and set some session values to variables, and try to echo those values, observe the output.Just to confirm Session is working fine...

Comment: it took two 13hr days and some help but after the 3rd rewrite things seems to be working with only one small server causation error that I just will have to live with.